# AutohotKey Tooltip attached to cursor permanently when PAUSED the script. Yet, once unpaused must change to UNPAUSED remaining for 2 seconds

Tags: autohotkey

I have tried many options that I have found here but none works exactly as I need it.

I have written this script to automate a series of processes that I do about different documents.

It works very well, although I often stop it when I find errors in those documents, but I also forget if I left it paused or if I reloaded it or even closed it.

For this reason I would like to apply a Tooltip saying PAUSED, attached to the cursor to tell me permanently when I have it paused without disappearing until I remove the pause. Yet, once I unpause the script I want the Tooltip to say UNPAUSED remaining for only 2 or 3 seconds.

Again:

I have tried many options that I have found here but none works exactly as I need it.

```
#NoEnv
#Warn
#Persistent

SendMode Input
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%

RandomSleep(x,y) {
Random, sleeprandom, %x%, %y%
Sleep %sleeprandom%
}

;——————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————



;   ————————    starts  1st |       3 sets of automated clicks  ———————— · ————————
|::

; Registers original cursor position.
MouseGetPos, StartX, StartY
RandomSleep(1000,1500)
;
Loop, 3
{
    MouseClick, left
    RandomSleep(600,1000)
    ;   ;   ;   ;
    MouseClick, left
    RandomSleep(600,1000)
;
    MouseMove, 0, 70, 100, R
    RandomSleep(600,1000)
;
    MouseClick, left
    RandomSleep(600,1000)
    ;   ;   ;   ;
    MouseClick, left
    RandomSleep(600,1000)
;
    MouseMove, 0, -350, 100, R
    RandomSleep(600,1000)
}
; Moves cursor back to its original position.
MouseMove, StartX, StartY
RandomSleep(50,150)

; Registers original cursor position.
MouseGetPos, StartX, StartY
RandomSleep(50,150)
;
MouseMove, 1912, 110
RandomSleep(50,150)
;
Loop, 21
{
    MouseClick, left
    Sleep, 50
}
;
; Moves cursor back to its original position.
MouseMove, StartX, StartY
RandomSleep(50,150)

MouseMove, 1912, 110
RandomSleep(1000,1500)
;
; Moves cursor back to its original position.
MouseMove, StartX, StartY
RandomSleep(50,150)

MouseMove, 0, -3, 100, R
RandomSleep(50,150)
 Return
;   ————————    ends 1st    |       3 sets of automated clicks  ———————— · ————————


;   ————————    starts  2nd 1       5 of 10 automated clicks    ———————— · ————————
1::
; Registers original cursor position.
MouseGetPos, StartX, StartY
Sleep, 50
;
RandomSleep(500,1600)
;
Loop, 5
{
    MouseClick, left
    RandomSleep(600,1000)
    ;
    MouseClick, left
    RandomSleep(600,1000)
    ;
    MouseMove, 0, -140, 100, R
    RandomSleep(600,1000)
}
MouseMove, 0, 770, 100, R
RandomSleep(500,1600)

Loop, 5
{
    MouseClick, left
    RandomSleep(600,1000)
    ;
    MouseClick, left
    RandomSleep(600,1000)
    ;
    MouseMove, 0, -140, 100, R
    RandomSleep(600,1000)
}

Sleep, 50

Loop, 21
{
    MouseMove, 1912, 110
    Sleep, 50
    ;
    MouseClick, left
    Sleep, 50
}

Sleep, 50

Loop, 3
{
    MouseMove, 1912, 1068
    Sleep, 50
    ;
    MouseClick, left
    Sleep, 50
}
; Moves cursor back to its original position.
MouseMove, StartX, StartY
Sleep, 50

; Mueve el mouse 18 píxeles hacia abajo:
MouseMove, 0, 18, 100, R
Sleep, 50
 Return
;   ————————    ends 2nd    1       5 of 10 automated clicks    ———————— · ————————


;   ————————    starts  3th Tab     Moves page 3 clicks up      ———————— · ————————
Tab::
; Registers original cursor position.
MouseGetPos, StartX, StartY
Sleep, 50
;
Loop, 1
{
    MouseMove, 1912, 1068
    Sleep, 50
    ;
    MouseClick, left
    Sleep, 50
}
;
; Moves cursor back to its original position.
MouseMove, StartX, StartY
Sleep, 50
 Return
;   ————————    ends 3th    Tab     Moves page 3 clicks up      ———————— · ————————


;   ————————    starts  4th Q       Moves page 22 clicks down   ———————— · ————————
q::
; Registers original cursor position.
MouseGetPos, StartX, StartY
Sleep, 50
;
Loop, 21
{
    MouseMove, 1912, 110
    Sleep, 50
    ;
    MouseClick, left
    Sleep, 50
}
;
; Moves cursor back to its original position.
MouseMove, StartX, StartY
Sleep, 50
;
 Return
;   ————————    ends 4th    Q       Moves page 22 clicks down   ———————— · ————————


;   ————————    starts  5th CapsLock    Moves page 2 clicks down    ———————— · ————————
CapsLock::
; Registers original cursor position.
MouseGetPos, StartX, StartY
Sleep, 50
;
Loop, 1
{
    MouseMove, 1912, 110
    Sleep, 50
    ;
    MouseClick, left
    Sleep, 50
}
;
; Moves cursor back to its original position.
MouseMove, StartX, StartY
Sleep, 50
;
 Return
;   ————————    ends 5th    CapsLock    Moves page 2 clicks down    ———————— · ————————


;   ————————    starts  6th A       Moves page 8 clicks down    ———————— · ————————
a::
; Registers original cursor position.
MouseGetPos, StartX, StartY
Sleep, 50
;
Loop, 7
{
    MouseMove, 1912, 110
    Sleep, 50
    ;
    MouseClick, left
    Sleep, 50
}
;
; Moves cursor back to its original position.
MouseMove, StartX, StartY
Sleep, 50
;
 Return
;   ————————    ends 6th    A       Moves page 8 clicks down    ———————— · ————————


;   ————————    starts  7th W       1 set of automated clicks   ———————— · ————————
w::
RandomSleep(900,1900)
;
MouseClick, left
RandomSleep(1400,1900)
;
MouseClick, left
RandomSleep(650,1400)
;
MouseMove, 0, 70, 100, R
RandomSleep(650,1400)
;
MouseClick, left
RandomSleep(900,1400)
;
MouseClick, left
RandomSleep(400,900)
;
MouseMove, 0, -71, 100, R
RandomSleep(400,900)
;
; Registers original cursor position.
MouseGetPos, StartX, StartY
RandomSleep(100,250)
;
Loop, 7
{
    MouseMove, 1912, 110
    RandomSleep(100,250)
    ;
    MouseClick, left
    RandomSleep(100,250)
}
;
; Moves cursor back to its original position.
MouseMove, StartX, StartY
RandomSleep(100,250)
 Return
;   ————————    ends 7th    W       1 set of automated clicks   ———————— · ————————



F5::Reload

Ctrl::Pause
```

Comment: To attach a Tooltip to the cursor permanently you need a timer or a loop. However, whenever the script is paused timers/loops will not run. The only solutions I see is a Tooltip e.g. on the top of the screen, a message box or a second script that sends a Pause command to this script and attaches a Tooltip to the cursor.

Comment: @user3419297 Do you mind to show me how, please? Can you please type here how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned:
To attach a Tooltip to the cursor permanently you need a timer or a loop.
However, whenever the script is paused timers/loops will not run.

The only solutions I see are

- a Tooltip e.g. on the top of the screen:
- a message box
- or a second script that sends a Pause command to this script and attaches a Tooltip to the cursor.

Best solution:

**Attach a Tooltip on the top left corner of the screen whenever the script is paused**:

```
; Use the OperateOnUnderlyingThread of the Pause command:

Ctrl::
If (A_IsPaused)
{
    Pause, , 1  
    Tooltip UNPAUSED
    Sleep, 3000
    Tooltip
}
else
{
    Pause, , 1
    CoordMode, Tooltip, Screen  
    Tooltip PAUSED, 0, 0
}
return
```

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Pause.htm#Parameters

**EDIT**

**Use a second script that attaches a Tooltip to the cursor:**

```
Ctrl::
DetectHiddenWindows, On
If (A_IsPaused)
{
    WinClose, %A_Temp%\Tooltip.ahk
    Pause, , 1
    FileDelete %A_Temp%\*.ahk
    FileAppend,
    (
    #NoTrayIcon
    Loop 30
    {
        Sleep, 100
        Tooltip UNPAUSED
    }
    ExitApp
    ), %A_Temp%\Tooltip.ahk
    Run %A_Temp%\Tooltip.ahk        
}
else
{
    WinClose, %A_Temp%\Tooltip.ahk
    Pause, , 1
    FileDelete %A_Temp%\*.ahk
    FileAppend,
    (
    #NoTrayIcon
    DetectHiddenWindows, On
    SetTitleMatchMode, 2
    Loop
    {
        If !WinExist("ScriptName.ahk ahk_class AutoHotkey")
            ExitApp
        Tooltip PAUSED  
        If GetKeyState("Ctrl")
            ExitApp
    }
    ), %A_Temp%\Tooltip.ahk
    Run %A_Temp%\Tooltip.ahk
}
return
```

**Replace "ScriptName"** by the name of the script.

**EDIT2**

The whole script:

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force
#Warn
#UseHook

SendMode Input
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%

FileDelete %A_Temp%\*.ahk

RandomSleep(x,y) {
Random, sleeprandom, %x%, %y%
Sleep %sleeprandom%
}
;——————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————

;   ————————    starts  1st |       3 sets of automated clicks  ———————— · ————————
|::

; Registers original cursor position.
MouseGetPos, StartX, StartY
RandomSleep(1000,1500)
;
Loop, 3
{
    MouseClick, left
    RandomSleep(600,1000)
    ;   ;   ;   ;
    MouseClick, left
    RandomSleep(600,1000)
;
    MouseMove, 0, 70, 100, R
    RandomSleep(600,1000)
;
    MouseClick, left
    RandomSleep(600,1000)
    ;   ;   ;   ;
    MouseClick, left
    RandomSleep(600,1000)
;
    MouseMove, 0, -350, 100, R
    RandomSleep(600,1000)
}
; Moves cursor back to its original position.
MouseMove, StartX, StartY
RandomSleep(50,150)

; Registers original cursor position.
MouseGetPos, StartX, StartY
RandomSleep(50,150)
;
MouseMove, 1912, 110
RandomSleep(50,150)
;
Loop, 21
{
    MouseClick, left
    Sleep, 50
}
;
; Moves cursor back to its original position.
MouseMove, StartX, StartY
RandomSleep(50,150)

MouseMove, 1912, 110
RandomSleep(1000,1500)
;
; Moves cursor back to its original position.
MouseMove, StartX, StartY
RandomSleep(50,150)

MouseMove, 0, -3, 100, R
RandomSleep(50,150)
 Return
;   ————————    ends 1st    |       3 sets of automated clicks  ———————— · ————————

;   ————————    starts  2nd 1       5 of 10 automated clicks    ———————— · ————————
1::
; Registers original cursor position.
MouseGetPos, StartX, StartY
Sleep, 50
;
RandomSleep(500,1600)
;
Loop, 5
{
    MouseClick, left
    RandomSleep(600,1000)
    ;
    MouseClick, left
    RandomSleep(600,1000)
    ;
    MouseMove, 0, -140, 100, R
    RandomSleep(600,1000)
}
MouseMove, 0, 770, 100, R
RandomSleep(500,1600)

Loop, 5
{
    MouseClick, left
    RandomSleep(600,1000)
    ;
    MouseClick, left
    RandomSleep(600,1000)
    ;
    MouseMove, 0, -140, 100, R
    RandomSleep(600,1000)
}

Sleep, 50

Loop, 21
{
    MouseMove, 1912, 110
    Sleep, 50
    ;
    MouseClick, left
    Sleep, 50
}

Sleep, 50

Loop, 3
{
    MouseMove, 1912, 1068
    Sleep, 50
    ;
    MouseClick, left
    Sleep, 50
}
; Moves cursor back to its original position.
MouseMove, StartX, StartY
Sleep, 50

; Mueve el mouse 18 píxeles hacia abajo:
MouseMove, 0, 18, 100, R
Sleep, 50
 Return
;   ————————    ends 2nd    1       5 of 10 automated clicks    ———————— · ————————


;   ————————    starts  3th Tab     Moves page 3 clicks up      ———————— · ————————
Tab::
; Registers original cursor position.
MouseGetPos, StartX, StartY
Sleep, 50
;
Loop, 1
{
    MouseMove, 1912, 1068
    Sleep, 50
    ;
    MouseClick, left
    Sleep, 50
}
;
; Moves cursor back to its original position.
MouseMove, StartX, StartY
Sleep, 50
 Return
;   ————————    ends 3th    Tab     Moves page 3 clicks up      ———————— · ————————

;   ————————    starts  4th Q       Moves page 22 clicks down   ———————— · ————————
q::
; Registers original cursor position.
MouseGetPos, StartX, StartY
Sleep, 50
;
Loop, 21
{
    MouseMove, 1912, 110
    Sleep, 50
    ;
    MouseClick, left
    Sleep, 50
}
;
; Moves cursor back to its original position.
MouseMove, StartX, StartY
Sleep, 50
;
 Return
;   ————————    ends 4th    Q       Moves page 22 clicks down   ———————— · ————————


;   ————————    starts  5th CapsLock    Moves page 2 clicks down    ———————— · ————————
CapsLock::
; Registers original cursor position.
MouseGetPos, StartX, StartY
Sleep, 50
;
Loop, 1
{
    MouseMove, 1912, 110
    Sleep, 50
    ;
    MouseClick, left
    Sleep, 50
}
;
; Moves cursor back to its original position.
MouseMove, StartX, StartY
Sleep, 50
;
 Return
;   ————————    ends 5th    CapsLock    Moves page 2 clicks down    ———————— · ————————


;   ————————    starts  6th A       Moves page 8 clicks down    ———————— · ————————
a::
; Registers original cursor position.
MouseGetPos, StartX, StartY
Sleep, 50
;
Loop, 7
{
    MouseMove, 1912, 110
    Sleep, 50
    ;
    MouseClick, left
    Sleep, 50
}
;
; Moves cursor back to its original position.
MouseMove, StartX, StartY
Sleep, 50
;
 Return
;   ————————    ends 6th    A       Moves page 8 clicks down    ———————— · ————————


;   ————————    starts  7th W       1 set of automated clicks   ———————— · ————————
w::
RandomSleep(900,1900)
;
MouseClick, left
RandomSleep(1400,1900)
;
MouseClick, left
RandomSleep(650,1400)
;
MouseMove, 0, 70, 100, R
RandomSleep(650,1400)
;
MouseClick, left
RandomSleep(900,1400)
;
MouseClick, left
RandomSleep(400,900)
;
MouseMove, 0, -71, 100, R
RandomSleep(400,900)
;
; Registers original cursor position.
MouseGetPos, StartX, StartY
RandomSleep(100,250)
;
Loop, 7
{
    MouseMove, 1912, 110
    RandomSleep(100,250)
    ;
    MouseClick, left
    RandomSleep(100,250)
}
;
; Moves cursor back to its original position.
MouseMove, StartX, StartY
RandomSleep(100,250)
 Return
;   ————————    ends 7th    W       1 set of automated clicks   ———————— · ————————

F5::Reload

Ctrl::
DetectHiddenWindows, On
If (A_IsPaused)
{
    WinClose, %A_Temp%\Tooltip.ahk
    Pause, , 1
    FileDelete %A_Temp%\*.ahk
    FileAppend,
    (
    #NoTrayIcon
    Loop 30
    {
        Sleep, 100
        Tooltip UNPAUSED
    }
    ExitApp
    ), %A_Temp%\Tooltip.ahk
    Run %A_Temp%\Tooltip.ahk        
}
else
{
    WinClose, %A_Temp%\Tooltip.ahk
    Pause, , 1
    FileDelete %A_Temp%\*.ahk
    FileAppend,
    (
    #NoTrayIcon
    DetectHiddenWindows, On
    SetTitleMatchMode, 2
    Loop
    {
        If !WinExist("ScriptName.ahk ahk_class AutoHotkey")
            ExitApp
        Tooltip PAUSED  
        If GetKeyState("Ctrl")
            ExitApp
    }
    ), %A_Temp%\Tooltip.ahk
    Run %A_Temp%\Tooltip.ahk
}
return
```

Replace "ScriptName" in the code by the name of the script.

Comment: Thank you! This works, but unfortunately it attaches the tooltip to the screen's upper left corner, not to the cursor, where I need it. Sorry, I'm 72. Can you please attach the tooltip to the cursor, if it is not too much asking?

Comment: See EDIT in this answer.

Comment: Thank you @user3419297 . Unfortunately this second code only shows the tooltip when UNPAUSED, but not when PAUSED. I apologize if I'm making you work too much.

Comment: Yes, I did. And it only shows the tooltip when UNPAUSED. I tried a copy of the same file changing the name of the file to ScriptName.ahk to avoid touching your code, and it didn't work too.

Comment: You are getting very close. Now it displays PAUSED attached to the cursor, but never disappears when UNPAUSED. However UNPASUED is not attached.

Comment: Yes, I saved and reload it, each new time.
I use the same code I posted here. Exactly the same. Then I substituted my Ctrl::Pause with your code, saving and reloading each new time. I also changed the name of the file to ScriptName.ahk to avoid touching your code.

Comment: Happily now UNPASUED is attached to the cursor. But the PAUSED tooltip never disappears when UNPAUSED.

Comment: That is exactly how I want it to work. That is why I chose Ctrl key as my hotkey to PAUSE/UNPAUSE, but it is not working this way as I explained before.

Comment: I did it. UNPAUSED Tooltip is working fine now, but PAUSED Tooltip never disappears.

Comment: Yes.  I changed the name of the file to ScriptName.ahk to avoid touching your code.

Comment: Still the same: UNPAUSED Tooltip is working fine now, but PAUSED Tooltip never disappears.

Comment: It opens a windows explorer window and it shows the Tooltip.ahk file on it, which disappears after closing the script.

Comment: No. It is the same content. It only shows only one instance of the file at the taskbar.

Comment: I use AHK Version 1.1.33.10 which is the current one.  This is the content of the Tooltip.ahk file:
`#NoTrayIcon
    DetectHiddenWindows, On
    SetTitleMatchMode, 2
    Loop
    {
        If !WinExist("ScriptName.ahk ahk_class AutoHotkey")
            ExitApp
        Tooltip PAUSED
    }`

Comment: I thank you very much for all your efforts. I will try to find a solution for this, and if I do it, I'll let you know. From the heart, I appreciate a lot your kindness! THANK YOU!

Comment: Something came to my mind right now! Can you create a new but empty Tooltip.ahk in substitution to the first one to allow the script to remove the PAUSED tooltip?

Comment: No. It doesn't work, even manually deleting the Tooltip.ahk file from the Temp directory. It keeps showing the PAUSED tooltip.
I also tried adding a second hotkey to pause it and the PAUSED tooltip never disappears. Thank you very much again.

Comment: Hello again @user3419297 . I apologize for late reply. I actually kept my Task Manager all the time during our tests, to close any possible ahk file open, but none was. Happily this late edit works charmingly perfect! Of course I'm very grateful to you. Probably you wish to edit that answer to make it clear as the final and working one, for any one else who needs help in a similar problem. Thank you very much for all your kindness and hard work my good friend. I feel very lucky to have a found someone this kind and gentle!